# Find the rates at which the volume V and the surface area S are changing with respect to time

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> The dimensions of a rectangular box are linear functions of time,
> $l(t), w(t), h(t).$ If length and width are increasing at $2$
> $in./sec$ and height is decreasing  at $3 \; in./sec$.
>
> Find the rates at which the volume V and the surface area S are
> changing with respect to time. If $l(0)=10$ and $w(0)=8$ and
> $h(0)=20$. Is V increasing or decreasing when $t=5$? What about $S$ at
> $t=5$

My attempt :-

$V = l(t)w(t)h(t) \Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dl} \frac{dl}{dt} + \frac{dV}{dw} \frac{dw}{dt} +\frac{dV}{dh} \frac{dh}{dt}= 2l(t)w(t) + 2l(t)h (t) -3l(t)w(t)$ ----> Equation 1

Similarly I can find it for the surface area.

My problem here is how do I get $l(5), w(5)$ and $h(5)$ using: $l(0)=10$ and $w(0)=8$ and $h(0)=20$ ?

Show I solve like this ?

$\frac{dl}{dt} = 2 \Rightarrow l(t) = 2t + C \Rightarrow C = 10  \Rightarrow l(t) = 2t + 10 \Rightarrow l(5) = 20?$ and plug it in equation $1$ to get rate of change of volume at $t=5$?

Please help me.

Comment: Yes, you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct. The rate of change is described exactly as you have mentioned, which by solving the simple differential equation you have, gives you the desired linear function (as also mentioned in the problem and which is logical since a rectangular box is described by linear functions regarding length, width and height) and you can find the values asked just by plugging it in.